# Is this possible? MS Access query selecting a field to be on top and others will be in alpha order

Tags: ms-access-2010, jet-sql

Example i have a table:

```
----------------------
 ID. | Color
----------------------
 A1.  | Red
 A2.  | Yellow
 A3.  | Blue
 A4.  | Black
-----------------------
```

Is this possible to sort a table like this? specify a field to be on top (example: Yellow) then the other records will be in alphabetical order.
the Color field can only be sorted.

```
----------------------
 ID. | Color
----------------------
 A2.  | Yellow
 A4.  | Black
 A3.  | Blue
 A1.  | Red
-----------------------
```

Is there a query related to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
Select
    ID,
    Color
From
    YourTable
Order By
    Abs([Color] = "Yellow") Desc,
    Color Asc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select *
from something
order by
 case when Color = "Yellow"  then "1"
 else Color 
end
```

Comment: Sorry. can you do that in MS Access sql?

Comment: `CASE WHEN` is T-Sql, not Access Sql.